# Google apps script html template issue

Tags: google-apps-script

How can I use a function that returns html within a string, inside a html template in google apps script ?

For example, here is my code.gs:

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('test').evaluate();
}

function getHtml(){
  return "<b> hello there </b>";
}
```

and in my html file 'test.html' I have the following:

```
<html>
 <?= getHtml() ?>
</html>
```

You will see the result is something like this:

[image]

How can I change this so it produces hello there in bold, without showing the tags ?

Many thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use force-printing:

```
 <?!= getHtml() ?>
```

as explained [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates).