# Google Script - Convert HTML-Template to string

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

So, I've been looking through StackOverlow for a while now, and the closest answer I found is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14729845/google-apps-script-html-template-issue).

I have built a template for sending emails and I'd like to reuse it for other purposes, such as the description of an event. I'm struggling to get a printout of the HTML template in a readable format, exactly as you get it in the email.

Here's the HTML template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
<p>Hi <?!= OOOCLIENTFIRSTNAME?>,</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here's the template code:

```
var emailtemplate  = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('XXXXX');
  emailtemplate.OOOCLIENTFIRSTNAME = clientfirstname;
var emailbody = emailtemplate.evaluate();
```

So, when I place it into the `sendEmail` method parameter's `htmlbody` property, it works perfectly and email is sent as planned. Here's the GmailApp code:

```
GmailApp.sendEmail(clientemail, 'TEST TITLE', '',
                      {htmlBody: emailBody.getContent()};
```

I want to get the result as a simple string, such as "Hi firstname".
I have tried to use `.getContent` but this results in getting the HTML source code, and not its output. Any ideas?

Comment: Please do not use code snippets for scripts that cannot be run without external dependencies or platforms. Use proper code formatting [Ctrl+K] instead: single backticks (“`”) for one-liners, property names and methods, code fences (“````”) for code blocks. Also please avoid chit-chat in questions, SO is not a forum, it is a Q&A website.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you a different approach:

### Just build your greeting in the Apps Script part before passing it to HTML.

Code:gs

```js
function myFunction() {
  var emailtemplate  = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index');
  var greeting = "Hi " + clientfirstname + ",";
  emailtemplate.OOOCLIENTFIRSTNAME = greeting;
  var emailBody = emailtemplate.evaluate();
  GmailApp.sendEmail(clienemail, 'TEST TITLE', '',{htmlBody: emailBody.getContent()});
  var reusedGreeting = greeting + " how are you?";
  Logger.log(reusedGreeting);
}
```

index.html:

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
<p> Hi <?!= OOOCLIENTFIRSTNAME?>,</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

### Why?

When you evaluate a template within a normal function, (opposed to  building a [WebApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) with a `doGet()` function that would allow you to pass a variable to serverside with [google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#code.gs)) there is no easy way to retrieve the inner HTML.
You'd need to either

- extract the string with Regex
- or parse the html as explained e.g. [here](https://tanaikech.github.io/2019/08/01/parsing-html-using-google-apps-script/)

Both solutions would be an overkill for what you are trying to do.